# Communication between Node.js and C# .Net using named pipe: 'data' event not fired

Tags: c#, node.js, named-pipes

I've setup a named pipe to have a nodejs app communicate with a C#  app. I am able to have the pipe connected, and send data from nodejs to C#, but the opposite doesn't work. i.e. When I write in the pipe from C#, the `data` event is never fired on the nodejs side.

**nodejs code:**

```
const net = require('net');
const pipeName = 'mypipe';

var server = net.createServer(function (client) {
    client.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("data: " + data.toString());
    });
});

server.listen(path.join('\\\\.\\pipe', pipeName), function() {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

**C# code:**

```
var pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "mypipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
pipe.Connect();

if (pipe.IsConnected && pipe.CanWrite) {
    var data = new byte[4] {0, 1, 2, 3};
    pipe.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

As I mentioned, when I write in the client socket in nodejs, I properly receive the data on C# side using `ReadyAsync`. The pipe client is created using `PipeDirection.InOut` so it should support reading as well as writing?

**EDIT:** Also tried using `BeginWrite`/`EndWrite` with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: I just discovered that if I write _something_ on the nodejs side, then suddenly the data I wrote on the C# side magically triggers the `data` event on nodejs side, as if C# `ReadAsync` made the nodejs server block?

Comment: I confirm that C# `NamedPipeClientStream.ReadAsync` will block `NamedPipeClientStream.WriteAsync` if a read is currently waiting for data. This means the pattern we often see on the net where a "StartReadAsync" is constantly waiting for data will reproduce this problem once you want to start writing to the pipe. A possible workaround would be to periodically _feed_ the read with a single throw away byte to allow the write to complete before starting another read.